# Angular 2 - loading css in multiple bundles based on currently active component

Tags: css, angular

My app will have 3 main branches.

- Public
- Client
- Admin

I plan to generate 3 css file bundles for each branch and would like the browser to cache them (huge files).

The problem is that I'm only able to cache the public.css in the index.html (styles.bundle.css). But no matter which approach I try, client.css and admin.css are injected into the head inside style tags

How do I:

1. Keep admin/client styles in .css file that is loaded **ONLY WHEN** admin/client component is launched?
2. Avoid any css being injected into head.

*If possible I would like to avoid webpack/systemJS approaches (if there are any).*